# Why python showing can't assign to literal in dictionary?

Tags: python

This was my program:

```
dict1={'R':'Rainy','S':'Summer','W':'Winter','A':'Autumn'}
dict1=['W']=['Spring']
>>> SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `=` in the second line is wrong. This should work:

```
dict1['W'] = ['Spring']
```

Note however that this way, you are setting `dict1['W']` to a list containing `'Spring'`, not to the string "Spring" itself.